# In postgres how can I create a custom type that is simply a timestamp truncated to minutes

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-types

I have a column "event_datetime" that is in many tables and I need it to be truncated to the minute. I dont want to create triggers in all the places to truncate it when i insert or update, or having to call date_trunc when I compare. Is it possible to have a custom type that is essentially a timestamp truncated?

Answer (score 2):

You can create [new base types in a low-level language like C](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html). You probably don't want to do that.

In PostgreSQL, the timestamp data types take an [optional precision](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html). But setting it to zero eliminates fractional seconds, not seconds.

I think the best you can do is to

- create a domain with a check constraint, and
- require all inserts and updates to call a function.

The `create domain` code looks like this.

```
create domain ts as timestamp 
constraint no_seconds check (VALUE = date_trunc('minute', VALUE));

create table ts_test (
  test_ts ts primary key
);

-- Doesn't work . . . 
insert into ts_test values (current_timestamp);
ERROR:  value for domain ts violates check constraint "no_seconds"

-- But this does.
insert into ts_test values (date_trunc('minute', current_timestamp));
```

This also allows comparisons without calling `date_trunc()`.

To avoid writing `date_trunc()` into every INSERT and UPDATE statement,

- revoke 'insert' and 'update' permissions on the base table,
- write a function to do the truncates and inserts, and
- call the function instead of using the base table directly.

But that just means you'll have to call *your* function in every insert and update statement instead of calling `date_trunc()` in every insert and update statement. It's not clear whether you're willing to do that.

Comment: thanks, you are right, I am not willing to do that. I took a look at custom base types in the documentation, and I would be willing to do that in C. But I feel I will be just re-inventing the wheel (very badly) since that's just a timestamp. I guess I ll search for some simple example and study it and decide.